# How to save the structure of my list of matrices from lapply-attack?

Tags: r, list, matrix

I want to convert a list of integer matrices to numeric. I know that lapply is not friendly to internal structures, but is there a lapply-solution?

```
mtList = list(matrix(sample(1:10),nrow=5),
              matrix(sample(1:21),nrow=7))
str(mtList)

# This works, and I could wrap it in a for loop
mtList[[1]][] = as.numeric(mtList[[1]])
mtList[[2]][] = as.numeric(mtList[[2]])
str(mtList)

# But how to use lapply here? Note that the internal
# matrix structure is flattened
mtList1 = lapply(mtList,function(x)x[] = as.numeric(x))
str(mtList1)
```

Comment: +1. I never thought about this behaviour before.

Comment: Me too.  I just learned a lot reading this question.  Interesting stuff.

Comment: +.5 for good question +.5 more for a great title :)

Comment: Well, the title proved wrong... It was the index, and not the lapply, that pierced...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return the value in your `lapply` workhorse function:

```
mtList1 = lapply(mtList,function(x) {
  x[] = as.numeric(x)
  x
})

str(mtList1)
# List of 2
#  $ : num [1:5, 1:2] 1 7 6 3 9 10 5 2 8 4
#  $ : num [1:7, 1:3] 21 3 15 14 6 4 18 17 9 8 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I returned x[] implicitly, which is the culprit

Answer (score 2):

A marginally simpler alternative could be to coerce by multiplying by `1.0` (or arguably, more robustly, raising to the power of 1.0)...

```
mtList1 <- lapply( mtList , "*" , 1.0 )
str(mtList1)
#List of 2
# $ x: num [1:5, 1:2] 2 8 1 5 7 9 3 10 4 6
# $ x: num [1:7, 1:3] 17 20 9 11 2 18 1 4 12 10 ...
```

Comment: You are right for the special case, but I used it as.numeric as an example for a more complex process

Comment: @DieterMenne another alternative is `x^1.0`. AFAIK this preserves `NA`, `Inf` and `NaN`.